# How can I install BCL (basic compression library)?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, c

I want to install [bcl (basic compression library)](http://bcl.comli.eu/download-en.html)

I need to copy a file into the C compiler’s (gcc)
lib directory, and copy a header file into the compiler’s (gcc) include directory.

I want to know where exactly these two directories are found in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 12.04 is out of support, and you will have problems installing any software on it. Your question is also very unclear in my opinion. To help with this problem, we would need to know what library you were trying to install (and which compiler...)

Comment: gcc compiler and bcl library ,i want to copy some of bcl header files into compiler's include directory and copy some library files into compiler's lib directory.So i need path for both.????@Zanna

Comment: @George@karel@Pilot6@Eric@Carvalho@Zanna  I have upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.now my question is relevant and you can reopen it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](/q/25961/175814)

Comment: @DavidFoerster this installation procedure is different not similar to [link]How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Makefile included for the GNU C compiler (gcc).

Just run make from the src directory, and
you will get a file called libbcl.a, which is a static link library that you can copy to your compiler’s
lib directory.

You may also want to copy the .h files to your compiler’s include directory.

only question is where these 2 directories (compiler's lib and compiler's include) are found!!!